# React Native - Three dots when text in TextInput is longer than TextInput and when not in focus

Tags: react-native

So I'll try to explain my scenario.

I have a *singleline* `TextInput`. When the user is `onFocus`, the text within the `TextInput` can be longer than the `TextInput` itself.

However, when the user is no longer `onFocus`, Android and iOS behave differently.

**iOS:**
Three dots are added to the end of the line and the beginning of the text is shown.

[image]

**Android:**
No changes are made.

[image: Behaviour in Android]

How can I make the TextInput in Android behave as it does in iOS for this particular scenario?

Thank you

Comment: Have you solved this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 const placeHolderLengthLimit = useMemo(
        () => (tooltip ? 31 : 37),
        [tooltip],
    );

    const placeholderString = useMemo(
        () =>
            placeholder
                ? Platform.OS === 'ios' ||
                  placeholder?.length <= placeHolderLengthLimit
                    ? placeholder
                    : placeholder?.slice(0, placeHolderLengthLimit) + '...'
                : undefined,
        [placeHolderLengthLimit, placeholder],
    );

                   <TextInput
                        placeholder={placeholderString}
                    />
```

Answer (score -7):

I don't know you got an answer or not but **ellipsizeMode** and **numberOfLines** will help to this query.

```
          <TextInput
            ellipsizeMode="tail"
            numberOfLines={1}
            ref={(textInput) => { this.textInput = textInput; }}
            style={}
            placeholder="Type a message..."
            onSubmitEditing={}
            onChange={}
          />
```

Comment: ellipsizeMode="tail" is only working in Text but not TextInput

Comment: Btw, the default value of ellipsizeMode in Text is tail.